# Replicate iOS Photos app collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm trying to figure out the best way of managing the two list/detail view of the photos app. My main question is, is it two collection views with two separate layouts? Or is it just one that is changing its flow layout? Right now I'm using two in two separate apps, but I'm not sure if it's the best way of doing it.

EDIT: I'm talking about the grid view of photos turning into the detail view of a single photo that is also swipeable (left/right).

Thanks

Comment: A screenshot of what looks like the part of the app you want to mimic is welcome.

Comment: Look for "layout to layout" transitions.

Comment: Clarified the post, sorry for the confusion @Larme

Comment: @DanielvanderMerwe have you got any solution? I am also facing the same problem. Please, reply if you got any solution.

Comment: @Stark, I did find a rough solution, the trick is to use the transition layout method between two flow layouts